# PHP not echoing back data from form submit

Tags: php, jquery

My page has an html form to collect email, first name, last name and a checkbox.  The form begins with this header:

```
<form action="echo_test.php" method="post" name='register' id='register'>
```

I submit the form with this button:

```
<div class="EMail_Pwd_JoinPage"><button class="btn_joinnow" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);" id="btn_submit" onclick="GetDate(); GetCkBx();">Submit data</button></div>
```

That calls this jquery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#btn_submit").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    form_data = $('form').serialize()
    console.log("Okay, I'm starting");
    console.log(form_data);
    console.log("More Info");
    GetDate();
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "echo_test.php",
        data: form_data,
        success: function (responseText) {
            console.log("Server Reply " + responseText);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("Okay, I failed" + error);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

It submits to echo_test.php on my server:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["firstname"]) . '!';
?>
```

In the onclick event submit code above it should reply from the server:

```
    success: function (responseText) {
        console.log("Server Reply " + responseText);
    },
```

But the Chrome dev console does not show any reply.  The other console.log messages above do appear correctly (including the serialized form data).

I asked a similar question back in May, but the situation is different here.

Why doesn't this code echo back from the server?

Comment: Since you're already defining a click event listener, why do you use `onClick` on the button.

Comment: Check the Network tab to see what parameters you're sending and the raw response.

Comment: What does `GetDate()` do? Maybe it's getting an error.

Comment: GetDate fills in the hidden date field in the form.  As far as I can tell it's not getting any errors.  One of the console.log messages echoes back the date and it appears correctly in the form data that are logged back to the console.  I'll remove that call and see what happens.

Comment: I removed the separate call to GetDate and now I DO get a response back.  I called GetDate from the button click event itself, and the date data are still in the form data, so that separate call was not needed and was causing this problem.

Comment: Good stuff @RTC222

Comment: Re your first question @dazed-and-confused, I make the two separate calls in the onCLick event so fill in the hidden fields for date and to get the checkbox state.

Comment: A little late @treyBake -- we've already solved it .

Comment: @RTC222 ah my bad^^ haha

Answer (score 0):

Idk what does onclick attribute mean,

```
onclick="GetDate(); GetCkBx();"
```

So i think just remove onclick attribute. And here new code,

```
<div class="EMail_Pwd_JoinPage"><button type="submit" class="btn_joinnow" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);" id="btn_submit">Submit data</button></div>
```

Also update your button action jQuery code,

```
$("#btn_submit").on("submit",
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, remove `onclick="GetDate(); GetCkBx();"` from the `button` tag and call those two functions in the click event handler you created.

New Button Tag:

```
<button class="btn_joinnow" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);" id="btn_submit">Submit data</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

in echo_test.php `return` the echo statement or use `die()`.

```
<?php
echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["firstname"]) . '!';
return;
?>
```